# Angular Typescript map array into class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have data that comes from a web api that looks like below. How do I map the product array into the Products, the reason for me doing that is that I need to transform the eating_time to javascript datetime.

My code below for the class where this.products = product will only store the array and the the list of product.

//Data from API

```
[ {datetime: "2017-06-25T07:45:00+08:00", name: "Apple", unit: 1, product: [{eating_time: "2017-06-25T07:45:00+08:00", qtytaken: 1, chart_bar=1 },
{eating_time: "2017-06-25T17:45:00+08:00", qtytaken: 1, chart_bar=1 },
{eating_time: "2017-06-25T23:55:00+08:00", qtytaken: 1, chart_bar=1 } ] 
]
```

// Class

```
class Product {
    eating_time: Date;
    qtytaken: number;
    chart_bar = 1;

    constructor({eating_time, qtytaken, chart_bar })  {
            this.eating_time = new Date(eating_time);
            this.qtytaken = dosage;
            this.chart_bar = chart_bar;
    }
}

export class ProductTaken {
    datetime: Date;
    name: string;
    unit: number;
    products: Product[];

    constructor({datetime, name, unit, product} )  {
        this.datetime = new Date(datetime) ;
        this.name = name;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.products = product ;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use interface or class without a constructor and `map` function

```
export interface ProductTaken {
    datetime: Date;
    name: string;
    unit: number;
    products: Product[];

}
```

Your service should have the `map` function

```
return this.http.get(...)
      .map(res => <ProductTaken>res.json())
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/XFzr6c7fRqsbSJbtThe1?p=preview)**

Comment: Without the Constructor the map function does not do the data transform.

Comment: it will definitely work. did you get a chance to modify the plunker and play around.

Comment: It will not work because of the type 'Date' of  'datetime' (Type mismatch betwen Date and string)

Comment: can you elaborate @Faly

Comment: In res.json(), datetime is of type 'string' whereas it's type specified by the interface is a Date.

Comment: but i have seen this working. this puts me in a confusion will go back and check again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have sort of found a solution but does anyone know if there is a better way then using forEach.

```
class Product {
    eating_time: Date;
    qtytaken: number;
    chart_bar = 1;

    constructor(eating_time, qtytaken, chart_bar )  {
            this.eating_time = new Date(eating_time);
            this.qtytaken = dosage;
            this.chart_bar = chart_bar;
    }
}

export class ProductTaken {
    datetime: Date;
    name: string;
    unit: number;
    products: Product[];

    constructor({datetime, name, unit, product} )  {
        this.datetime = new Date(datetime) ;
        this.name = name;
        this.unit = unit;
        let prodarray = [];
        product.forEach(function(element) {
          prodarray.push(new Product(element.eating_time, element.qtytaken, element.chart_bar));
        this.products = prodarray ;
        }
}
```